# Elasticsearch issues with .NET spatial data types

Tags: .net, postgresql, elasticsearch

I'm trying to create an index for a set of objects that need to have a lat/lon attribute.

I've tried several data types, including Nest's GeoLocation data type and NetTopologySuite's Point data type.  Entity framework core is complaining about Nests's data type (says cannot bind).  And I'm getting a strange error when using the Point data type, which seems to be coming from Elasticsearch.  When I try to run the migrations, I get an error that is several thousand lines long.  I've copied what I think are some relevant bits below.  Any idea what is going on?

```
Build started...
Build succeeded.
Loaded environment: Development
Initializing data with Bogus...
Stack overflow.
   at Elasticsearch.Net.Utf8Json.Internal.DoubleConversion.Double.AsUint64()
   at Elasticsearch.Net.Utf8Json.Internal.DoubleConversion.Double.Significand()
   at Elasticsearch.Net.Utf8Json.Internal.DoubleConversion.Double.AsDiyFp()
   at Elasticsearch.Net.Utf8Json.Internal.DoubleConversion.Double.NormalizedBoundaries(Elasticsearch.Net.Utf8Json.Internal.DoubleConversion.DiyFp ByRef, Elasticsearch.Net.Utf8Json.Internal.DoubleConversion.DiyFp ByRef)

...

at DynamicClass.Serialize(Byte[][], System.Object[], Elasticsearch.Net.Utf8Json.JsonWriter ByRef, **NetTopologySuite.Geometries.Point**, Elasticsearch.Net.Utf8Json.IJsonFormatterResolver)
```

For further context, here is the bit of code where the Elasticsearch client is being created.

```
var settings = new ConnectionSettings();

        var client = new ElasticClient(settings);
        var defaultIndex = "product";

        client.Indices.Create("product", c => 
            c.Map<Product>(m => 
                m.AutoMap().Properties(ps=> 
                    ps.Point(s => 
                        s.Name(n => n.Location)))));
```

Comment: Are you trying to create the index in code? Or are you using Kibana? 

I encourage you to first try writing the mapping in Kibana and building the index there before translating it to code. It makes for quicker iterations and testing and clearer error messages.